# How do you search for a range of number using Secure Random?

Tags: java

Please help me out I would like to generate random numbers from say 1 - 10 using 
SecureRandom, how do I do this?

Comment: Check this link : http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/random-number-generation-java/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do by this operation:

`Random rand = new SecureRandom()
// 1 to 10 inclusive.
int number = rand.nextInt(10);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution it's work.

```
public static void main (String args[]) {

try {
 SecureRandom number = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
 // Generate 10 integers 1..20
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   System.out.println(number.nextInt(10));
 }
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
 // Forward to handler
 }
 }
```